# USB recording and RCA Stereo recording, which of them is better?

Tags: sound-design, audio-recording, audio, recording, pro-tools

I worked with Smart Volume Management (SVM or normalizing sound) that be a capability of Creative Sound Card for Live Music Recording (we have one mixer and two mics on two separate line we get the people and speaker sounds).

I buy this sound card [X-Fi Creative](http://uk.creative.com/p/sound-blaster/sound-blaster-x-fi-titanium-hd)

I buy a Mixer Dynacord 1000-3 as [Described Here](http://www.dynacord.com/en/products/7/5/29/102/index.html).

We used the stereo output from Mixer to input of creative sound card (RCA) and record good.

Today We decide to use USB-24 bit output from our mixer and plug it to one device that accept usb input for recording and has capability of SVM. Computer without the SVM capability is not good for us. Our question is as follows:

> if we buy a Creative Sound Blaster X7  and like always use streo and
>   RCA for recording, has differ quality to use a device that accept USB
>   input for recording and has SVM capability? (I means quality of stereo port is differ with USB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a USB output, then it is already digital.  Do not go back to analog.  Every generation of analog connection results in further signal degradation and quality loss.  Going to digital stops the quality loss.  The only reason you might not want to go digital as soon as possible would be if the quality of the analog to digital converter was going to be much better, but moving from a 24 bit ADC in a mixer vs a consumer X-Fi, you will have much better quality in the sound board.  If you got a true professional audio capture card then that might not hold true, but it certainly holds true for going in to an X-Fi via RCA cables.

Comment: Thanks very useful. But I still two question: 1) is it good to record via x7 or better to buy a sound card? I want to use usb output from mixer. I ask my second question after answering this. Thanks

Comment: @user355834 - while it generally isn't a good idea to ask additional questions in comments, I'll help you out here simply because it wouldn't be a good new question.  There really isn't a good answer to that question without knowing the specifics of what you are looking at, what you are trying to record, what you quality needs are and what your budget is like.  Try it with the USB feature you have, see how it sounds, if it doesn't sound good enough, look for an audio interface that has a better capture capability, but be ready for them to get pricey fast.

Comment: Sorry ok i get it. I want to record live vocal with perfect and as high as quality as possible. Minimum 24 bit.

Comment: I'm sorry if my english is not good. Really up to yet i didn't get my answer. My challenge is remain that which external sound card can take output of my mixer usb and record it?

Comment: We might have better luck figuring out your answer for that in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45276/discussion-on-answer-by-aj-henderson-usb-recording-and-rca-stereo-recording-whi).

Comment: Would you please let me to continue three hours next?

Comment: @user355834 sure, I might not be able to get on then, but I'll try putting some more detail in the chat there and you can respond whenever you get a chance.

Comment: Thanks please add more detail i answer it when i get home